# Get the class that SetClassLongPtr uses

Tags: winapi, setclasslong

I have multiple firefox profiles running each with multiple windows.
When I pick a random window from each profile and run this code on that windows `hwnd` it sets the icon for all windows in that profile. `SetClassLongPtr(targetWindow_handle, GCLP_HICONSM, ctypes.cast(hIconSmall, ctypes.uintptr_t));`

I was wondering how to get this class?

I tried using `GetClassName` on all window handles however that returns `MozillaWindowClass` for all windows regardless of profile. Yet `SetClassLongPtr` does not apply across profiles, so that's how I know that the class of windows in first profile is different from class of windows in second profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private window classes are registered per-process. So whilst each of your windows used a window class with the same name, those names are defined relative to a per-process namespace. So, the window class with name `foo` in process A is a different window class from that named `foo` in process B.

From this knowledge, and the facts you report in the question, it would appear that Firefox uses separate processes for distinct profiles. But I could well imagine that different versions of Firefox behave differently. That seems to me to be an implementation detail that you should not rely upon.

Comment: Ah! That's the trick, thanks man! I'll use `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to get that then.